# Permission denied with github action and terraform

Tags: git, github, terraform, github-actions, cicd

I have a problem with github action and terraform.

I have fives repository on my github account. I'm able to clone/push/pull them from my computer thanks to my ssh key.

On my main.tf file, I've created some module when the source are my other repository :

```
module "1" {
    source   = "git@github.com:my_user/XXX.git"
}

module "2" {
    source   = "git@github.com:my_user/XXX.git"
}

module "3" {
    source   = "git@github.com:my_user/XXX.git"
}

module "4" {
    source   = "git@github.com:my_user/XXX.git"
}
```

If I execute these commands from my computer :

```
terraform init
terraform plan
terraform apply -auto-approve
```

Everything works well.

If I try make a github action, I've this error at the terraform init step :

```
│ git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
│ fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
│ 
│ Please make sure you have the correct access rights
│ and the repository exists.
```

Why I've this error while each repo are on the same github account ?

I've tried to create a github token with the full rights and I've putted it in the secrets section of my git and in the env section of my .yaml :

```
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
```

But I've the same error.

There is someone to help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Github token can only do https based git authentication, but you're using SSH urls to git repos.  You can configure git to automatically rewrite them for you with `InsteadOf`:

```
git config --global url."https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
```

Comment: If it's correct I think @Morph59 can also use the HTTPS address in the `source` field, like:
`source = git::https://github.com/my_user/XXX.git`

Comment: yeah possibly, but the existing ssh auth may be used in other places, namely locally

Answer (score 0):

you are using [SSH syntax not HTTPS](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#github). so you must have a valid SSH key on your server.

Make sure you have this file on your server (if not create your SSH key)
'/root/.ssh/id_rsa' and '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'

Also make sure you either deployed 'id_rsa.pub' key under your user or under the repos you want to check out

NOTE: your SSH key name MUST BE 'id_rsa', do not use a different name, it won't work!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a bug on the Windows version, as described [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-google-vault/issues/45#issuecomment-531903592).

The solution nhart-alf proposes is to set your `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` environment variable to point to the SSH client you wish to use.

Here's some PowerShell to do that:

```ps
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('GIT_SSH_COMMAND', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe')
```